# Undefined reference to `PaUtil_GetRingBufferReadAvailable' when compile paex_record_file.c from Portaudio using Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, compilation, portaudio

I need to compile PortAudio's *paex_record_file.c* file using Eclipse and CDT on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Dev libraries (libportaudio-dev) was installed via Synaptic.
I create new Eclipse project and create (copy) this *only* file to it (so project contains only one user source file 'paex_record_file.c', 1752 2011-09-08 03:21:55).

Then i use Eclipse's Pkg-config to add 'portaudio' (dev) library.
But it not compiles with error

```
../src/paex_record_file-test.c:47:27: fatal error: pa_ringbuffer.h: No such file or directory
```

Then source branch taken from git

```
$ git clone https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
./configure
make
sudo male install
```

But still get same error (no 'pa_ringbuffer.h').

Then during blind trials and errors i use Project - Properties - C build - Settings - Tool settings - Includes, and add '/home/test/portaudio/src/common' path which contains needed .h file, and (this) error disappear.

**Question 1**: Is this step is correct use of Eclipse settings in this case? (i believe not, because i never need to use *this* setting before).

But then it shows multiple errors like

```
/home/doc/prog/paex_record_file-test/Debug/../src/paex_record_file-test.c:110: undefined reference to `PaUtil_GetRingBufferReadAvailable'
```

and this is unrecoverable.

**Question 2.** How it can be fixed using Eclipse, BUT without copying all Portaudio source tree to my project?

I have *pa_ringbuffer.o* file somewhere in system, but no any something like pa_ringbuffer.so files.
I have compiled and running under Eclipse other PA apps which are do not use PA's ring buffer, and just

```
#include "portaudio.h"
```

and adding PA lib via PkgConfig is enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look into the portaudio.git :

```
cd portaudio/
find . -name pa_ringbuffer.h
The reply is : ./src/common/pa_ringbuffer.h
```

... so you will have to copy the header to a location, where it can be found. **But** : Do not expect to compile a single file → often not possible with a complex application. I.e. the setup is meant for compiling the complete portaudio/.

Comment: When i try this way, Eclipse's driven linker becomes more hungry and need more and more source .h and even .c files. Is this really correct and professional way to copy part of source tree to my project? Can i use .o files placed at separate (Portaudio) folder using only link to these, to avoid recompiling already compiled parts? And why other examples from Portaudio are does not need anything unusual, it is my error, Eclipse error, or Portaudio error?..Thanks.

Comment: So copying one by one source files and how having ~half of source tree in my project, i ended up with pa_front.c, which have *'Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice()'*, which in turn replaces one comes from dev libs - and it is not work, no any audio device it sees.
So, even having a fork of PA source, it is not work in case of '.paex_record_file.c'

Comment: Trying to compile on other environment, i get additional problem because this example just not work with Linux. It contains the following line: _/* Start up a new thread in the given function, at the moment only Windows, but should be very easy to extend to posix type OSs (Linux/Mac) */_. It is fully impossible for me to write this from scratch. So, compared to previous problem, this gives me much less (zero) chances to get ring buffer work. (Any help with code example very welcomed). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add those 3 files to source code as well as main.c , then it compiled.
I use Code Block, Mingw c compiler

/portaudio/src/common/pa_allocation.c

/portaudio/src/common/pa_ringbuffer.c

/portaudio/src/os/win/pa_win_util.c

[code block IDE view of 3 files added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlNQO.jpg)